# Passing a structure appears to corrupt data

Tags: c#, c++, interop, c++-cli, cryptoapi

I have a program that needs to pass data from C++ to C# and back for processing.  In order to do this, I have retrieved a structure, converted it into a byte array and then converted it back on the other end.  However, when converting it back, the data is not correct, even though the memory dump shows that the values in memory for each variable are identical.

Here is the code to retrieve the value:

```
array<Byte> ^ GetPublicKeyBlob(String ^ ContainerName) {
    const TCHAR * tContainer = context->marshal_as<const TCHAR*>(ContainerName);
    HCRYPTPROV hProv = NULL;
    CryptAcquireContext(&hProv, tContainer, MS_ENHANCED_PROV, PROV_RSA_FULL, CRYPT_MACHINE_KEYSET);
    DWORD dwKeySize = 0;
    CryptExportPublicKeyInfo(hProv, AT_SIGNATURE, X509_ASN_ENCODING, NULL, &dwKeySize);
    PCERT_PUBLIC_KEY_INFO pbKey = (PCERT_PUBLIC_KEY_INFO)calloc(dwKeySize, sizeof(BYTE));
    CryptExportPublicKeyInfo(hProv, AT_SIGNATURE, X509_ASN_ENCODING, (PCERT_PUBLIC_KEY_INFO)pbKey, &dwKeySize);
    array<Byte> ^ retVal = gcnew array<Byte>(dwKeySize);
        for(int i = 0; i < dwKeySize; i++)
            retVal[i] = ((BYTE*)pbKey)[i];

    free(pbKey);
return retVal;
}
```

Then on the other end, I change it back to a PCERT_PUBLIC_KEY_INFO structure with the following code:

```
BYTE * cpiBuffer = (BYTE*)calloc(_PublicKey->Length, sizeof(BYTE));
for(int i = 0; i < _PublicKey->Length; i++)
    cpiBuffer[i] = _PublicKey[i];
PCERT_PUBLIC_KEY_INFO cpi = (PCERT_PUBLIC_KEY_INFO)cpiBuffer;
```

When looking at them in a memory dump, pbKey, retVal, _PublicKey, cpiBuffer and cpi all have the exact same values.  But when looking at cpi as a structure, the Algorithm.pszObjId points to some erroneous memory location and when I try to use it in a function, it fails.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What do you mean by "Algorithm.pszObjId points to some erroneous memory location"?  Is it a pointer?

Comment: It is an LPSTR.  When I expand the structure in a watch, it points to a memory location not inside the structure whereas when I got the original value, it was pointing to a location within the structure.

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef struct _CRYPT_ALGORITHM_IDENTIFIER {
  LPSTR            pszObjId;
  CRYPT_OBJID_BLOB Parameters;
} CRYPT_ALGORITHM_IDENTIFIER, *PCRYPT_ALGORITHM_IDENTIFIER;
```

As you can see, pszObjId is a pointer, it's contents are somewhere in memory. By casting the PCERT_PUBLIC_KEY_INFO structure to byte array you are only getting the value of the pointer, not what it points to.

On a side note, I'm not sure why are you marshaling as TCHAR*, if you want bytes then you should use char* or unsigned char*. If UNICODE is defined TCHAR will be wchar_t and that might make some difficulties.

Comment: TCHAR* is just force of habit.  This is thrown-together code and not production.

How would I get the original structure back if not from casting?

Comment: I don't have a definitive answer for you because I don't know how these structures are created, who allocates the string and who is responsible for freeing it. But I'm guessing that you could create a function that knows how to serialize the struct, member by member, serializing string as a null terminated character array or with a size prefix.

Comment: The first call to CryptExportPublicKeyInfo returns the length of the buffer needed for the CERT_PUBLIC_KEY_INFO structure.  I then allocate that amount of memory and call the function again and it passes the data into the buffer.

Comment: The function returns the size of the structure, but doesn't take into account heap allocated members. pszObjId is counted as one pointer. Think how would you implement a copy constructor for this struct and it's members. Then instead of copying all the contents to a new object, copy to memory buffer and you have the serialization.